# How can I play an AWS S3 video file in jwplayer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, jwplayer

my Jwplayer code here

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  
 jwplayer("container").setup({
        
        file: "rtmp://s1dik636ldu2l9.cloudfront.net/1442383829.mp4",
        width: 800,
        height: 469,
        autostart: 'true',
        skin: 'roundster',
        primary: 'flash'
        
        }); 

</script>
```

But I got configuration error when including the this path..

Comment: Mistagged as PHP, this should be tagged as JavaScript and (I think, from the code) jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that you are loading a .3gp file, that is not supported.

This is what we support:

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-support

Comment: hi Ethan.. Mp4 videos also not loaded. i have error like **Error loading player  could not load player configuration**

Comment: You have to provide a link to where you are running this then.